# Conflict between mathabx and accents packages

Tags: errors, packages, compiling, export, mathabx

I'm having problems with the [mathabx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx?lang=en) package, which I use for the `\widecheck` symbol. When I try to compile it interrupts the process and sends me to the package documentation, specifically referencing this line:

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\ring}          {0}{mathb}{"38}
```

[image]
[image]

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{mathabx}


\begin{document}

hello world

\end{document}
```

It seems to be a conflict between the mathabx and the accents package (it compiles if I remove one of the two). Has anyone ever had this problem and know of a fix? I'm using a mac with the full TeX Live documentation and Latexian as an editor.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It would be better to have a minimal example of code that shows the issue and also the error message you get.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for taking the time of reading my question. I updated it with the error message I was getting. As for the minimal working example, the compilation error isn't of any specific usage of the package, it's the package itself. I could post my whole preamble, but it's kind of a mess.

Comment: Also a minimal example of code producing the error is needed (not an image): just a small document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added the minimum working example. I noticed it might be a conflict between the accents and the mathabx package (I kind of need both).

Comment: Just load `accents` *after* `mathabx`.